# Can't find my mistake in building a balanced binary tree from a sorted array (segfault)

Tags: c, data-structures, segmentation-fault

I'm working on this assignment, and while I'm still new to programming in C, I thought I had a better grasp of memory reference and pointer use...

What I'm trying to do is create a balanced binary tree from a sorted array. I'm throwing segmentation faults when I try to call on my tree-building function. If I leave that function call out and just print my arrays, everything compiles and runs fine with expected output.

I've got my nodes of the tree built like this:

```
typedef struct leaf{
    int value;
    struct leaf* left;
    struct leaf* right;
} LEAF;
```

My sorting/tree-building function library:

```
LEAF* balance( int n[], int first, int last ){
    int mid;
    LEAF* ptr = NULL;
    printf( "in Balance" );
    if ( first > last ) return NULL;

    mid = first + (last - first)/2;
    ptr->value = n[mid]; 

    ptr->left = ( balance( n, first, mid-1 ) );
    ptr->right = ( balance( n, mid+1, last ) );

    return ptr;        
}
void ins ( int* n, int length ){  //Don't THINK the problem lies here, 
                                    I've used the algorithm before and can 
                                    print out the sorted array
    int i, j, key;

    for( i = 0; i < length; i++ ){/*all indexes*/
            key = n[i]; /*pick out index and store in variable*/
            for( j = i-1; j >= 0; j = j-1 ){/*all objects left of i*/
                    if ( n[j] < key) break;/*stop and insert*/
                    n[j + 1] = n[j];/*shifting all objects left*/
            }
            n[j + 1] = key;/*insertion expression*/
    }
}
```

Back in main(), I build my array n[] and call on balance() like so:

```
int main (void){
/****** initializations */
    int* n;
    char buffer[20];
    FILE* fp;
    int numMax = 5;
    int lastIndex = 0;
    int j;
    char* filename = "numbers.txt";
    LEAF* root = NULL;
    n = malloc ( numMax * sizeof(int*) );

    if ( ( fp = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL ){
            printf( "cannot open %s\n", filename );
            exit( 1 );
    }

/****** allocating storage array and inputting */
    printf( "initial array size: %d", numMax );
    while( fgets( buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp ) != NULL){
            n[lastIndex] = atoi( buffer );
            lastIndex++;

            if ( lastIndex == numMax ){  /*When max num reached, double allocation*/
                    numMax = numMax * 2;
                    if ( ( n = realloc( n, numMax * sizeof(int) ) ) == NULL ){
                            printf( "Cannot allocate more mem." );
                            exit( 1 );
                    }

                    printf( "\nReached limit... increasing array to %d possible indexes.", numMax );
            }

    }
    lastIndex--;

/****** sort*/
    ins( n, lastIndex+1 );

/****** build tree*/
    root = balance( n, 0, lastIndex );
```

I know there's a lot of code in here that's probably not necessary to addressing my problem. I put pretty much all of my code in this post, just on the chance that I messed up somewhere I don't expect. I expect that it's probably a really simple solution that's going to make me feel dumb.  I figure the dumber I feel, the less likely I am to make a mistake twice!

A strange thing though: I don't even get to see the printf( "in Balance" ) statement, and if I put other printf()'s within a couple of lines above my root = balance() function call, they don't print, either, before the segfault. Maybe that's some dynamic in the compiler that I don't understand?

Comment: Learn to: compile with **all warnings and debugging informatiopn** (e.g. with `gcc -Wall -g` on Linux) and improve your source code till no warnings are given by the compiler; **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb` on Linux); end your `printf` format strings with `\n` (or call `fflush` appropriately).

Comment: I've been trying to learn to use gdb. I've watched a few tutorial videos and read a bit about it. Most of how to use debuggers like that go over my head a bit... 

As far as compiling, I've been using the command line switches -pedantic and -std=c89 (because my teacher said so). What's the difference between that and -Wall -g?

Comment: `-Wall` gives you almost all warnings (with `-Wextra` giving even more) and `-g` produces debugging information in the object file, useful to `gdb`

Comment: Fantastic, I'll start using those! thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I can't see how the `ptr` variable is getting assigned in the `balance` function.  `ptr->value` will always result in dereferencing null unless you point the pointer somewhere (either allocate some memory for it, or point it towards some existing memory).

```
LEAF* ptr = NULL;
printf( "in Balance" );
if ( first > last ) return NULL;

mid = first + (last - first)/2;
ptr->value = n[mid];
```

Comment: That's the answer... *sigh* 

Silly mistake indeed. I didn't even have to try it, I just kinda set my head in my hands and kicked myself.

Comment: Don't worry, that's the first part of the realization that programming is a matter of learning to find your silly mistakes :)

Comment: I think you're absolutely right, and I really like that people in this field all seem to understand that we're all going to make silly mistakes. From what I've seen so far, people don't seem to hold it against you.